# Border Radius not working on wider screen

Tags: html, css, border, border-radius

I'm learning from a project which uses cards with border-radius 50px. However, on wider screen, the border is not working. It's a quite simple code, bud I don't understand why this is happening
Can you help me?

```
        <div class="panel panel1" style="background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1448375240586-882707db888b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8Zm9yZXN0fGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&w=1000&q=80')">
            <h3>Explore the world</h3>
        </div>

body {
   font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
   margin: 0;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   height: 100vh;
   overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
   display: flex;
   width: 90vw;
   overflow: hidden;
}

.panel {
   background-size: auto 100%;
   background-position: center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   height: 80vh;
   border-radius: 50px;
   color: white;
   cursor: pointer;
   flex: 0.2;
   margin: 15px;
   position: relative;
   transition: flex 0.7s ease-in;
   overflow: hidden;
}

.panel h3 {
   font-size: 24px;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 60px;
   left: 200px;
   margin: 0;
   opacity: 0;
}

.panel.active {
   flex: 2;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

[Border radius not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbNRk.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

looking at the print screen it looks like the border radius is working, but the div is being cut, maybe you can solve this by adding a width to the panel

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).